# Docker: Webservice in container returns no results

Tags: docker, networking

I am new to docker so sorry for the noob question.

I set up a web service running in a docker container on ip `127.0.0.1:5000`. I want to reach this webservice from my host.

I start the container with this command: `docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:300:5000 -it myContainer bash -c "...start webservice..."`

My expectation is that when I access localhost on port 300 I would connect to my service running in the container, right?

When I `curl` this port from my host I get an `curl: (52) Empty reply from server` (not an connection error) which I don't understand - it seems my payload got lost.

When logging into the container executing the curl command within the container in which the services is running I get the expected output. The webservice seems to properly reply on requests.

Thus, I struggle to understand the problem why/how the payload is lost between my container and host?

My host system is OS-X my container Ubuntu. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: you don't need -p `127.0.0.1:300:5000`, just set `-p 300:5000`

Comment: what's the output on terminal of `docker-machine ip default`

Comment: It says there is no default machine `docker-machine ls` shows no machine at all.

Comment: please stop your docker container and check if that port isn't being used by a different service on the host machine (`netstat -p tcp | grep 300`)

Comment: No service running on this port. I also changed the host port to other ports but the result stays the same.